# MySQL; How to reset id and set new, start at

Tags: mysql, sql, identification

The id's in one of my MySQL tables actually start from 34567 (34568, 34569, 34570…).

How can I reset all these id's and set 123 as start value: 123, 124, 125, 126…?

Or is there a way to make every id `-34444`: `34567-34444=123`?

P.S. `ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 124;` isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: Don't mess with the auto-increment. Why would you want to do it?

Comment: Id's are just id's, don't bother about their values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, you probably shouldn't worry about the values of the ids.  By definition, they shouldn't have any real meaning anyway.

Having said that, you should be able to just update them as you would any other column:

```
update table_name
set id = id - 34444
```

You could then reset the starting `AUTO_INCREMENT` value so that the next row inserted has a sequential id:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = <whatever the maximum id is + 1>;
```

Be aware that doing that will rebuild the table, so it could take a while if it has many rows.

Comment: Thank you very much. The first code is what I was looking for. (It's so unbelievable logical. Why didn't I had this idea?) P.S. I know id's shouldn't get changed manually.

Answer (score 1):

**If you have deleted all table records** and you want to start from 123 for the auto-increment field, then use the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=123;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
select (id-34444) as id from your_table;
```